# Complex plane deprived from or deprived of closed disk?

Tags: article-writing

Which of the following phrases are correct?

"Complex plane deprived **of** closed disk"
or
"Complex plane deprived **from** closed disk"

Comment: None of the two.

Comment: What you probably mean is "The complex plane with a closed disk removed."

Comment: The second is simply wrong. The first is standard English and it does mean what you intend it to mean, but it's very non-standard "mathematical English". See the first comment...